# inserting records into table via python

Tags: python, sqlite

**I have two list columns[],rows[]. I am trying to insert records in a table called docs.** 
Columns in the table docs are :  `(('suggestedpa', None), ('loadid', None ))`

**CODE**

```
 conn.execute('INSERT INTO docs ('+str(columns)+') VALUES ('+str(rows)+')')
```

**Error**
*`sqlite3.OperationalError: table docs has no column named 'suggestedpa', 'loadid'`*

Comment: columns=['suggestedpa', 'loadid']                                                                    rows=['U.S. Bank National Association Intellectual Ventures II LLC', '233996']

Comment: conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS docs(%s)" % ", ".join(columns))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is :

```
columns=['suggestedpa', 'loadid']
rows=['U.S. Bank National Association Intellectual Ventures II LLC', '233996'] 
columnsHelp = map(str,columns)
columnsStr = ",".join(columnsHelp) # this is now a string
rowsHelp = map(str,rows)
#rowsStr = ",".join(rowsHelp) # this is now a string val1,value
# do this 
rowsStr = "'" + "','".join(map(str, rowsHelp)) + "'"
conn.execute("INSERT INTO docs ("+columnsStr+") VALUES ("+rowsStr+")")
```

Good luck

Comment: Sir still i am getting error while execution: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "National": syntax error. i can provide you whole data that i am trying to insert to take a deeper look and help me out, you can drop me mail on anuj.masand@gmail.com if interested.

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "National": syntax error

Comment: You can use this line : rowsStr = "'" + "','".join(map(str, rowsHelp)) + "'"

Comment: thanks for the support buddy. i found out the element causing error, handled it, now working fine. Thanks @lazy_coder.

Comment: No problem, i learn a lot by trying solving problems on stackoverflow